# Using ASP.NET MVC ViewModels with Durandal without boilerplate

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, durandal

I'm writing a small app based on John Papa's "Hot Towel" template, meaning MVC 4 and Durandal.
As someone with mostly MVC experience it seems most "correct" to use MVC's "Models" with their Data Annotations for validation.
I also don't want to write the viewmodels OR the validation twice, which seems a reasonable enough desire.

So far I've easily figured out how to use `ko.mapping` for loading the ViewModel and its data from the server side using JSON, and binding my form to it. Great. But what about the validation part? For the life of me I can't find a single solution for this on the internet, as I'm not interested in making use of Razor (I've seen some solutions using its `HtmlHelpers`).

At the moment, the best way I see is to transform the ViewModel objects on the server to a simpler JSON object using reflection, where these annotations will be represented as members. Like so:

```
public object TransformVM(object vm)
    {
        var properties = vm.GetType().GetProperties();
        var result = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            var attributes = p.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            var displayName = attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a is DisplayNameAttribute) as DisplayNameAttribute;
            result.Add(p.Name, new
            {
                value = p.GetValue(vm),
                displayName = displayName != null ? displayName.DisplayName : ""
            });
        }

        return result;
    }
```

meaning instead of getting the view model as this json

```
{ Email: 'something@somewhat' }
```

I get a two-levelled object like

```
{ Email: { value : 'something@somewhat', required: true, displayName: 'e-mail' } }
```

and then using ko's binding this way:

```
<label data-bind="text: post.Email.displayName"></label>
<input type="text" data-bind="    value: post.Email.value" />
```

This of course means writing a "translation" for every single `DataAnnotation` I wish to use, which can get cumbersome.

So is this the right way or am I pitching myself into a hole too deep to get out of?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going with the same architecture as John's HotTowel, why not use Breeze JS validations? Your model will have the basic validation rules from EF/database, then you can enhance using custom validators.

Read more here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation